# Css in Rails 3.2 Agile Web Development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have to use Rails 3.2 cause of my hosting. However, i installed the

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

and i have also copyed the css from *the book Agile Web Development with Rails, 4th Edition, Rails 3.2 (The Pragmatic Programmers) - 2011* of the layout of their app.
I put it here:

**C:\Bitnami\chiarini\app\assets\stylesheets**

```
    /*
     * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
     * listed below.
     *
     * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
     * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
     *
     * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
     * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
     *
     *= require_self
     *= require fullcalendar
     *= require_tree .

    */

    #banner {
      background: #9c9;
      padding: 10px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid;
      font: small-caps 40px/40px "Times New Roman", serif;
      color: #282;
      text-align: center;

      img {
        float: left;
      }
    }

    #notice {
      color: #000 !important;
      border: 2px solid red;
      padding: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 2em;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      font: bold smaller sans-serif;
    }

    #columns {
      background: #141;

      #main {
        margin-left: 17em;
        padding: 1em;
        background: white;
      }

      #side {
        float: left;
        padding: 1em 2em;
        width: 13em;
        background: #141;

        ul {
          padding: 0;

          li {
            list-style: none;

            a {
              color: #bfb;
              font-size: small;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

i put the view of my layout:

**C:\Bitnami\chiarini\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>aaa</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">

        <div id="banner">
             <%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
             <%= @page_title || "aaa" %>
         </div>
         <div id="columns">
             <div id="side">
                <ul>
                 <li><a href="http://www....">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://www..../faq">Questions</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://www..../news">News</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://www..../contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
         <div id="main">

            <% if notice %>
              <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
            <% end %>
            <% if alert %>
              <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
            <% end %>

             <%= yield %>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

And it's how it appears:

[image]

And it should be like this:

[image]

I don't know where is the problem. is it possible that bootstrap overwrite something of the css?

Comment: Did you run " generate bootstrap:install" command after install twitter-bootstrap-rails gem rails.

Comment: i follewed this link: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails   I'm on windows , so i cant' install less. I used rails generate bootstrap:install static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `devise` gem for authentication and authorization. Please skip `before_filter :authenticate_admin!` or `before_filter :authenticate_user!` for your root path.

You can also customize your sign in(login) template in `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`